# iOS: AVSpeechSynthesizer - supports offline?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer for TTS functinality. I want to know whether AVSpeechSynthesizer supports offline.

I tried few texts in few languages, It supports offline. I want to sure it supports offline for all languages or not.

```
Does AVSpeechSynthesizer support offline for all the supported language?
```

Comment: If you are already using it, can't you turn airplane mode an test it?

Comment: how its , check this `recognitionTaskWithRequest`

Comment: @FabioBerger, I tried. It supports offline . But i want to make sure it supports offline for all languages

Comment: According to [Use Your Loaf](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/synthesized-speech-from-text/), which also provides a nice class diagram, **it is offline in all languages**.

Comment: @the4kman, Are you sure? Does apple mention this in developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the AVSpeechSynthesizer API will allow you to support offline TTS functionality.

The languages that are supported are listed below as of iOS 8.1:

Arabic (ar-SA)

Chinese (zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-TW)

Czech (cs-CZ)

Danish (da-DK)

Dutch (nl-BE, nl-NL)

English (en-AU, en-GB, en-IE, en-US, en-ZA)

Finnish (fi-FI)

French (fr-CA, fr-FR)

German (de-DE)

Greek (el-GR)

Hebrew (he-IL)

Hindi (hi-IN)

Hungarian (hu-HU)

Indonesian (id-ID)

Italian (it-IT)

Japanese (ja-JP)

Korean (ko-KR)

Norwegian (no-NO)

Polish (pl-PL)

Portuguese (pt-BR, pt-PT)

Romanian (ro-RO)

Russian (ru-RU)

Slovak (sk-SK)

Spanish (es-ES, es-MX)

Swedish (sv-SE)

Thai (th-TH)

Turkish (tr-TR)